# django - DetailView how to display two models at same time

Tags: python, django

I have two models : Advertisment and Banner

when I using "generic view" DetailView How can I Bring  two models at the same time The code below bring only one Advertisment

My url.py

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', DetailView.as_view(
    model               = Advertisment,
    context_object_name = 'advertisment',
), name='cars-advertisment-detail'),
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure, just override `get_context_data` to add stuff to the context.

```
path('<int:pk>/', YourDetailView.as_view(), name='cars-advertisment-detail'),

class YourDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'advertisment'
    model = Advertisement

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """
        This has been overridden to add `car` to the template context,
        now you can use {{ car }} within the template
        """
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['car'] = Car.objects.get(registration='DK52 WLG')
        return context
```

Answer (score 4):

For me, it's easier to make a custom mixin like this:

```
class ExtraContextMixin(object):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ExtraContextMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update(self.extra())
        return context

    def extra(self):
        return dict()
```

Later you can just subclass this mixin and then override the `extra` like this:

```
class MyDetailView(ExtraContextMixin, DetailView):

    def extra(self):
        extra = Extra.objects.all()
        return dict(extra = extra)
```

I think this is cleaner rather than overriding `get_context_data`