# Accessing the models fields DetailView

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

The problem i am having is I can't access a model's fields in the html  `{{ profile.slug }}`.  In the template I can   access the model, let me show you.

I have 2 models Profile, and Oferto.
In Detail view on the Oferto Model, I want to link to the user's profile who created the Oferto.
the Oferto Model has a field user,

I am trying to lookup the `profile.slug`  that coresponds to the Oferto.user

The following is seen in the browser from a test

```
[<Profile: Red>]
Name: oFFER

User: Red

Description:

Time:    9

Stelo:   None

Requirements:9
```

and the template is as follows

```
{% block content %}
<a>{{ profile }}</a>

    <p>Name:        {{ oferto.name }}</p>
    <p>User:        {{ oferto.user }}</p>



    <p>Description: {{ oferto.descripion }}</p>
    <p>Time:        {{ oferto.time }}</p>
    <p>Stelo:       {{ oferto.stelo }}</p>
    <p>Requirements:{{ oferto.requirements }}</p>
                <hr>
    <p>Location:    {{ oferto.location }}</p>
    <p>tags:        {{ oferto.tags }}</p>
    <p>{{ PROJECT_URL }} / {{ STATIC_URL }}{{ oferto.image }}</p>


{% endblock %}
```

if i try to use `profile.slug`  it just comes up blank and is not in the html

```
views.py

class OfertoDetailView(ExtraContextMixin,DetailView):
    model = Oferto

    def extra(self):
        profile = Profile.objects.all()
        return dict(profile = profile)

class ExtraContextMixin(object):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ExtraContextMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update(self.extra())
        return context

    def extra(self):
        return dict()
```

if your wondering why I am using a mixin see an answer from 
[django - DetailView how to display two models at same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14936160/django-detailview-how-to-display-two-models-at-same-time)

My Models

```
# Ofertoj.models.py
class Oferto(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    # profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=3000)
    time = models.DecimalField(max_digits= 10000000,decimal_places =2,null= True)
    stelo = models.DecimalField(max_digits= 10000000,decimal_places =2,null= True)

    location = models.TextField(max_length=3000)

    slug = AutoSlugField(('slug'), max_length=128, unique=True, populate_from=('name',))
    tags = tagging.fields.TagField()



    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Ofertoj',blank=True, null=True)

    requirements = models.TextField(max_length=550000,blank=True, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('oferto_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_tags(self):
            return Tag.objects.get_for_object(self) 

# turtle.models.py

class BaseInfo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    contact_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=75)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=3000)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=3000)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=3000)
    code = models.IntegerField()
    country = models.CharField(max_length=3000)

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d',blank=True)

    slug = AutoSlugField(('slug'), max_length=128, unique=True, populate_from=('name',))
    tags = tagging.fields.TagField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_tags(self):
        return Tag.objects.get_for_object(self) 
# profile.models.py
class Profile(BaseInfo):
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=15000000)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('profile_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})


# tempilo.profiles.UserProfiles
from models import Profile


class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'identifier'

    profile = OneToOneField(Profile,primary_key=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`profile` is a queryset, not an instance. Querysets don't have a `slug` attribute.

You either need to get a specific instance of Profile in your extra method, or iterate through the profiles in your template.

Comment: Ok So I know I can get the one user :Red so how do I get an instance of the user :Red

Comment: You don't show your models, so it's hard to help. If there is a relationship between ofero and user and profile, then you shouldn't need your extra method at all: you can just follow that relationship in the template (eg `oferto.user.profile`) - but we'd need to see the models to say exactly how to do it.

Comment: Added a couple of models

Comment: So, what I said above was correct: remove the `extra` method altogether, and just use `{{ oferto.user.profile }}` in the template. (Although I don't know why you're using a separate Profile when you're already overriding the User model, you could just put your profile fields there.)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `[<Profile: Red>]` is visible in the test output indicates that you are passing `Profile` instance to the template correctly.

Therefore the problem lies within `profile.slug`. Are you sure that you have `slug` field on your `Profile` class?